# How do find the optimal values for these expressions?

Tags: optimization

Say I have three constants a, b and c (all > 0) and three variables x, y and z (all >= 0).  I want to find values for x, y, z which maximise the lowest of the following:

```
ax - y - z
-x + by - z
-x -y + cz
```

How can I find these values?

**EDIT**: just corrected expressions -- variables and constants were wrong way around

**EDIT**: x, y and z all must be >=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you are trying to solve a minimax (or rather, maximin) type problem.  Formally, your statement is

$\max \min \{ax-y-z, -x+by-z, -x-y+cz\}$, and you have not listed any other constraints.

A standard trick is to reformulate this problem as a constrained maximization problem.  We can do this by introducing an auxiliary variable $\gamma$,

$\max_{\gamma, x,y,z} \gamma$ subject to $ \gamma \leq f_i(x,y,z)$ for $i=1,2,3$

where $f_i(x,y,z)$ corresponds to each of the linear functions you stated.

This is nothing but a linear program now, which can be solved using your favorite method.

Comment: Yes that's it -- but I'm afraid I don't now how to solve linear programs -- please could you explain?

Comment: Sorry, but I think "how to solve linear programs" is really beyond the scope of this board.  I can only suggest finding a book (Convex Optimization by Boyd is good) or starting with wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).  If you know how to use MATLAB, there are built in solvers (linprog).

Comment: Okay, I'll read up.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: A good book is Dantiz and Thapa's "Linear Programming".